# How to make zsh search configuration in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Looking to make my `~` a cleaner place, I would like to move as much user configuration files into `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, which is `~/.config` by default. So I would like to store all my zsh user files in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh/`. So far already have this:

```sh
% ls $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh/
histfile  zsh_cache zshrc
```

Easy, you just have to fill your `~/.zshrc`. Now the trickiest part seems to make zsh read directly $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh/zshrc without sourcing it from ~/.zshrc. How would you proceed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One may edit `/etc/zsh/zshenv` to set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` directories and `$ZDOTDIR`. This require write privilegies on this files though.

So provided that `$HOME` is defined when zsh read it (I don't know if it's the case), you may add to your `/etc/zsh/zshenv`:

```bsh
if [[ -z "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" ]]
then
        export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config/"
fi

if [[ -d "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh" ]]
then
        export ZDOTDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh/"
fi
```

Comment: Note that files in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh/` must be named with a leading dot, `.zshrc` if you want that zsh read them automatically. I don't know if zsh enable to change that with variables like `$ZSHRC`.

Answer (score 9):

It is good practice to not put a `/` at the end of any variable holding a certain path.

For example, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh` translates to `"$HOME/.config//zsh"` and the `/` repeats because `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` ends with a `/`.

So I think your answer should be -

```
if [[ -z "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" ]]
then
        export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
fi

if [[ -d "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh" ]]
then
        export ZDOTDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh"
fi
```

Comment: However, `zsh`(`bash` too) automatically replaces a set of consecutive forward slashes with a single one. So `$HOME/.config//zsh` isn't totally bad.

Comment: Can you provide any source to your claim that it's a bad practice to end variables in a slash if it's a directory? For me it signals the reader that the path is a directory, not a file, and signalling fellow programmers (and myself) is always a good thing. I read in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) about Pathname Resolution in 4.11, and it only briefly mentions trailing slashes, not mentioning how to store variables of these. Nevertheless, in 3.266 (Pathname) it explicitly says trailing backslashes are optional.

Answer (score 5):

Variation to psychoslave's answer which uses ${HOME}/.zshenv to initiate the environment.  No root access needed.

```
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:=${HOME}/.config}
export ZDOTDIR=${ZDOTDIR:=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/zsh}
source $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
```

This was discussed on [this thread](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2012/msg00344.html) on the zsh-users mailing list.

You may want to consider saving history in XDG_DATA_HOME. Specifications can be found at [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html).

Comment: Thank you. However that doesn't go in direction of removing all configuration files from the `~` directory. :(

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper for zsh that executes `zsh` after setting the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` to where you want zsh to look for the config files.

See: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I think that combined with editing files in `/etc/zsh/` that should do the trick.

Comment: but it DOES remove the need to edit as root /etc files which can be a royal PITA when maintaining configs across various machines, Your ~/.zshenv can simply be a symlink to a dropbox synced file.